# jQuery-Keep slidedown DIV visible if mouseover it

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, mouseover, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a link (BTN-SLIDE) that, when clicked (and not when hovered), slides down another DIV (called PANEL), something like a dropdown menu.

I want to make sure the dropdown DIV fades out when:
a) The mouse leaves the link
b) the mouse leaves the dropdown DIV

But I also want the dropdown DIV to stay visible while mouse is over it.

This is the code I have. The problem is that when I click to open the dropdown DIV (#panel) and leave the link (.btn-slide) without mouseovering the #panel, then the #panel will never close.

On the other hand if I set the #panel to close on mouseleaving the link, then the #panel will close even if I'm mouseovering it.

Any solution? Thanks!

```
<a class="btn-slide" href="#”>Click here to open Panel</a>    
<div id="panel"><p>ahsjdhkashdkasjhd</p></div>

$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
  $("#panel").slideDown(500);
});

     $("#panel").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#panel").slideUp(500);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap both elements in a parent element and get the mouseleave trigger from that.  http://jsfiddle.net/UCrQF/

Comment: How could I possibly not think about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem.  If this answers your question properly, please mark it as answered.  Thanks!

Comment: One more question: if my link is a small 20x20 icon and the #panel div is a 300x300 box just under the icon, then your method will not work if I have more than one drodown one next to another

Comment: To be more specific, it will not work as the dropdown box width will be 300px, so the "hover" area will be larger than the icon iteself, which is only 20px

Comment: Hmm.. can you use JSFiddle to demonstrate?  Markup/CSS will play a huge role in how we debug this.

Comment: Just an image to show what I mean. The blue dot is the btn-slide link icon, while the #panel is the box below. The red bow is the wrapper. So I leave the icon moving the mouse on the left, then it will still hover the wrapper box http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/830/asdcvio.png/

Comment: This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/UCrQF/2/ As you can see if the link is just a small icon (I used a zero to represent it), then the wrapper will have the same width of the #panel. So If I exit the "zero" on the right, then the box will still be there!

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution can be made by stopping the event aggregation in the mouse over function of the drop down content.

```
function topMenuSetup(){
  $(".top-nav-dropbtn").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideDown('medium');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
    });

    $(".top-nav-dropdown-content").hover(
      function() {
          $(this).stop(true, false);
      },
      function() {
          $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
      });
}
```